# On mouse over the main tab drop down content should be displayed

Tags: javascript, css

Here - [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Pranab14/3nzekje2/3/) When I mouse over the Software tab it shows content to the right, this is fine. But when I move cursor on the right pane the content disappears. So when user moves cursor on right pane the content should be displayed and the Software tab should be active (i.e. should have white background) and also this should be the default state once user mouse over on "Products & Services" tab.
Here is reference link - http://www.onbase.com/ (Please move cursor on second tab i.e. Solutions, I want the same navigation like this tab).`enter code here`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/3nzekje2/6/)

the issue was the sub sub menu was `20px` away so you was hovering on empty space to go to sub menu so i changed the empty space with the `padding`

```
#navME ul li .container .sub dl dd div.subWrapperLeft {
    left: 200px; /* changed from 220 to 200*/
    top:0; /* changed from top: 10 to 0*/
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    padding:0 10px; /** added **/
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick help! Also can you please give me a solution for mouse over issue. When user move cursor on Products and Solution, then Software should be default tab with Software's right pane content visible. (Here is reference link - http://www.onbase.com/ (Please move cursor on second tab i.e. Solutions, I want the same navigation like this tab)